# Full screen Vimeo Video Issue & YouTube Player API Reference for iframe in IE7

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a site (which is only viewed using Internet Explorer 7) that is made up of 5 sections and in section 2 I am currently using Vimeo to embed a video. The requirement is that the user has to watch all of it before proceeding to the next section. In order to achieve this I have used event listeners which only activate the ‘Next’ button to proceed when all of the video has been watched (Works Great)

Another requirement is for users to be able to play the video in full screen but the problem I have using Vimeo is that it does not support the option to hide the progress bar when a video is playing in full screen, this allows the user to skip the video. After researching around and contacting Vimeo support I can confirm that hiding the progress bar can only be achieved when viewing the video in standard mode when you have subscribed to the pro account (which I have). 
I looked into targeting the CSS classes within the iFrame, and setting a display none value on the controls div but this is something that can’t be done.

I have looked at using YouTube as an alternative and you are able to hide the progress bar in full screen using this markup

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0?&fullscreen=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=1></iframe>
```

I’ve done some reading on using the YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) but it says that one of the requirements is that the user's browser must support the HTML5 postMessage feature - INTERNET EXPLORER 7 DOES NOT SUPPORT IT :(

Could anyone suggest how I can achieve this, either by hiding the progress bar using vimeo in full screen or by implementing the youTube Iframe API to work with IE7?

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a parameter to remove the controls in a Vimeo video on their [page on embedding](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding#universal-parameters). Also, the Vimeo [FAQs](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#why-is-the-control-bar-hidden-on-my-embedded-video) say that the control bar gets hidden on an embedded video when it's less than a specified number of pixels wide.

You might have to do some sneaky CSS styling stuff instead. I did manage to find an [article](https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/) on hiding controls on an HTML5 video when viewing it fullscreen, but it said that IE does not support the full-screen API, so I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do is actually possible on IE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to look at a hacky way of targeting the CSS within the iframe so I can set the doc containing the controls to display none. Seen a few script examples but not got them to work as of yet! I will keep searching and experimenting. Ps Vimeo support have said there is no way I can hide the progress bar in full screen mode